# Assigning key's to array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

I'm trying to solve this problem. Essentially, I have a array of keys, and an array of values within objects, and I want those values to have keys.

Below is my best attempt so far - usually use python so this is a bit confusing for me.

```
var numbers = [3, 4, 5,6]

var selection = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 5, 4, 3], [2, 9, 4]]
var result = [];

for (arr in selection) {
numbers.forEach(function (k, i) {
result[k] = arr[i]
})
};

console.log(result);
```

The output I'm looking for is like this,

```
results = [{3:1,4:2,5:3,6:4}, {..},..]
```

Love some pointers to getting the right output.

Note. This is for google appscript! So can't use certain javascript functions (MAP I think doesn't work, unsure of reduce).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate function which take keys and values as arguments and convert it into object using `reduce()`. Then apply `map()` on `selections` and make an object for each subarray using that function

```js
var numbers = [3, 4, 5,6]
var selection = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 5, 4, 3], [2, 9, 4]]

function makeObject(keys, values){
  return keys.reduce((obj, key, i) => ({...obj, [key]: values[i]}),{});
}
const res = selection.map(x => makeObject(numbers, x));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` on selection and `Object.assign`

```js
var numbers = [3, 4, 5, 6];

var selection = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [6, 5, 4, 3],
  [2, 9, 4]
];

var result = selection.map(arr =>
  Object.assign({}, ...arr.map((x, i) => ({ [numbers[i]]: x })))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) object from scratch for each number array:

```js
const selection = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [6, 5, 4, 3],
  [2, 9, 4],
];

function objMaker(numarr) {
  const numbers = [3, 4, 5, 6];
  numarr.forEach((num, i) => (this[numbers[i]] = num));
}
console.info(selection.map(numarr => new objMaker(numarr)));
```